# Executing an (insertion in database (hibernate)) job with Spring and Quartz in Eclipse does not do anything but there is no error?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

I use Hibernate, Spring, Quartz in Eclipse.

My goal is to insert periodically some values in a table of my Oracle database.

Hibernate, Spring and Quartz work fine, I tested them.

**But somehow, even if it works, insertions are not actually performed in database whereas no error is printed on the eclipse console.**

I precise that the insertions work fine if I do them outside Spring and Quartz.

Well, I will not give you all my code because I know that there is no real mistake, **it is more suggestion about why nothing is performed in spite of the absence of error that I want**.

**But still, here is the code of my Quartz job :**

```
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;

public class RunMeJob extends QuartzJobBean {
private RunMeTask runMeTask;

public void setRunMeTask(RunMeTask runMeTask) {
    this.runMeTask = runMeTask;
}

protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {

    runMeTask.doMe();

}
}
```

**Where runMeTask is the following class :**

```
public class RunMeTask {
public void doMe() {
    Configuration configuration=new Configuration();  
      configuration.configure();  
      ServiceRegistry sr= new    ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();  
      SessionFactory sf=configuration.buildSessionFactory(sr);  
      Session ss=sf.openSession();  
      ss.beginTransaction();
      Query query = ss.createSQLQuery("SELECT MAX(PRIX) from HISTORIQUE_PRIX");
      List l = query.list();
      BigDecimal nouvelleDonnee = new BigDecimal (((BigDecimal) (l.get(0))).floatValue());
      ss.save(new HistoriqueProduit(new HistoriqueProduitId(new Integer(1), nouvelleDonnee)));
      System.out.println(nouvelleDonnee);
      ss.getTransaction().commit();  
      ss.close(); 
}
}
```

I did not put the imports so it's clearer.

**So, to explain what I do :**

I have a table HISTORIQUE_PRIX with two columns : NUMERO and PRIX. 
Periodically, I do the following job : insert the values (1, max(PRIX) + 1) in the table where max(PRIX) is the max of the column PRIX. 
So, if at the begininng, my table had only one line `1, 1` then the following lines will be inserted :

```
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
...
...
1, 100
1, 101
1, 102
...
```

**And I do that every 30 seconds with a simpleTrigger as you can check through my Spring bean configuration xml file :**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="runMeTask" class="com.mkyong.common.RunMeTask" />

<!-- Spring Quartz -->
<bean name="runMeJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">

    <property name="jobClass" value="com.mkyong.common.RunMeJob" />

    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="runMeTask" value-ref="runMeTask" />
        </map>
    </property>

</bean>

<!-- Simple Trigger, run every 30 seconds -->
<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="30000" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />

</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="runMeJob" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Then I run my app :**

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Quartz.xml");

}
}
```

**Then, in the eclipse console, I get this :**

```
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
août 25, 2015 7:32:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
août 25, 2015 7:32:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
août 25, 2015 7:32:36 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
août 25, 2015 7:32:36 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
août 25, 2015 7:33:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
août 25, 2015 7:33:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
août 25, 2015 7:33:36 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
août 25, 2015 7:33:36 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
août 25, 2015 7:34:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
août 25, 2015 7:34:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
```

**As you can see, the minutes advance...but no insertion is done, it just checks `Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml` then nothing**. It is quite weird.

I thought, maybe it is because 30 seconds are not enough and the insertion has no time to be executed that the second begins (but still it has no meaning because every job is within a transaction that has to be committed before the second job begins). So I let 4 minutes for example but it does not change anything.

I should also mention that even reading does not work. If I want to print a value that I select from a table, same problem occurs : nothing happens but no error.

**EDIT :**

After Sergey Pauk suggestion. This is what I did : I modified the class RunMeTask.java as following :

```
public class RunMeTask {
public void doMe() {
    Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
      System.out.println("ok");
      configuration.configure();
      System.out.println("ok0");
      ServiceRegistry sr= new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();  
      SessionFactory sf=configuration.buildSessionFactory(sr);  
      Session ss=sf.openSession();  
      ss.beginTransaction();
      System.out.println("ok1");
      Query query = ss.createSQLQuery("SELECT MAX(PRIX) from HISTORIQUE_PRIX");
      List l = query.list();
      BigDecimal nouvelleDonnee = new BigDecimal (((BigDecimal) (l.get(0))).floatValue());
      System.out.println(nouvelleDonnee);
      System.out.println("ok2");
      ss.save(new HistoriqueProduit(new HistoriqueProduitId(new Integer(1), nouvelleDonnee)));
      System.out.println("ok3");
      ss.getTransaction().commit();  
      ss.close(); 
}
}
```

I added many `System.out.println();` to see where the problem occurs. And as only `ok` is printed in the console, it means that it stops after `confuguration.configure()`...But still, I do not know why and even if it "stops", there is no error, jobs continue to be executed but only the part above `configuration.configure()` is executed.

So, anyone would have a suggestion ? Thanks !

Comment: i'd suggest you to add some logging into `doMe` method so that you see what and when is really executed

Comment: Ok thanks @Sergey Pauk. Your suggestion was really helpful. In RunMeTask.java,  I added `System.out.println("ok")` after `Configuration configuration=new Configuration();`  and I added  `System.out.println("ok0")` after `configuration.configure();`. Well, only ok appears, that means that everything stops at line `configuration.configure`. This is already something instructive. Now, the goal is to know : why ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, believe me or not, I do not understand anything. But after hundred of attempts, it finally worked perfect.

I really can not understand why it did not work before, still a mystery to me...